# Datatables with JSON Ajax datasource

Tags: json, django, rest, datatables, tastypie

Given a RESTful API built with Django 1.10 and Django-Tastypie 0.13.3 that gives the following response to a GET request:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": "/api/v1/serverwinpatchresults/?limit=20&offset=20",
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 178
    },
    "objects": [
      {
        "date_installed": true,
        "downloaded": "True",
        "installed": "True",
        "patch_guid": {
            "dateinserted": "2016-08-14T09:34:47",
            "description": "https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2757638",
            "guid": "013af7d6-ec9f-4def-ae41-007d211f9fbc",
            "kb": 0,
            "needsreboot": "False",
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/winpatches/013af7d6-ec9f-4def-ae41-007d211f9fbc/",
            "severity": "Moderate",
            "title": "Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2757638)",
            "userinput": "False"
        },
        "patch_result_id": "16013af7d6-ec9f-4def-ae41-007d211f9fbc",
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/serverwinpatchresults/16013af7d6-ec9f-4def-ae41-007d211f9fbc/",
        "server": {
            "active": 1,
            "cpuarch": null,
            "customer": {
                "active": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "name": "SOMENAME",
                "resource_uri": "/api/v1/customers/1/"
            },
            "customer_0": null,
            "customername": null,
            "domain": null,
            "fqdn": null,
            "host": null,
            "hwaddr_interfaces": null,
            "ip4": null,
            "ip6": null,
            "kernel": null,
            "kernelrelease": null,
            "master": null,
            "mem_total": null,
            "nodename": "SOMENODENAME",
            "num_cpus": null,
            "num_gpus": null,
            "os": {
                "active": 1,
                "name": "Windows",
                "os_id": 1,
                "resource_uri": "/api/v1/operatingsystems/1/"
            },
            "os_0": null,
            "os_family": null,
            "osrelease": null,
            "path": null,
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/servers/16/",
            "saltversion": null,
            "server_id": 16,
            "shell": null,
            "tag_name": "SOMETAGNAME",
            "timezone": null,
            "uuid": null,
            "windows_domain": null,
            "wintel": null,
            "zmqversion": null
        }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The following HTML:

```
<table id="patch_report" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Server</th>
          <th>Guid</th>
          <th>Downloaded</th>
          <th>Installed</th>
          <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#patch_report').DataTable( {
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type" : "GET",
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/serverwinpatchresults/",
            "dataSrc": "objects"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "server.nodename" },
            { "data": "patch_guid.guid" },
            { "data": "downloaded" },
            { "data": "installed" },
            { "data": "date_installed" }
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

I am trying to figure out why my table is failing to render. Not only is it failing to render, but it is failing to render without error.

When I look at the requests being made from the Django dev server in PyCharm I see the following:

> "GET /api/v1/serverwinpatchresults/?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=server.nodename&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=patch_guid.guid&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=downloaded&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=installed&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=date&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1471378715102 HTTP/1.1" 200 30115

which, to me, seems like the GET request from Datatables to my API is working and returning *something*. However nothing is rendered except the search bar, number of entries selector, and the table headers. I thought I would be able to pull the data I wanted out of the API using `columns` to drill down the exact fields I need. However this does not appear to be the case.

---

So this was an operator error. It appears I was calling the API via `localhost` while loading the page as `127.0.0.1` so cross-origin was kicking in.

The issue now is that pagination does not work, as well as filtering. I believe Brian Kates is correct, and I am failing to consume the metadata from the API via Datatables for things like the number of total records and the number of filtered records, however I am unable to find solid examples in the documentation on how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things simpler, I would start by turning server side off.  It's not related to an ajax datasource and requires you to return extra parameters.  For example, you need to return the number of total records and the number of filtered records.  I didn't see that in your code.  See the documentation:  https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/.  Because you've omitted those params, that could be why you are not seeing anything.

Edit:  Look at the server side processing docs:  https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters.  Paging works by sending a start and a length in the sent paramters.  You obviously need to use that information to query for your data.

As for server side filtering, you need to set the records total and records filtered.

Comment: see my edit above. I was able to get the page to display but any and all search, pagination, or filtering functionality at all is missing. I believe it is what you say, but the documentation is vague on how to implement said functionality.

Comment: @beardedeagle Turn off serverside processing. That's what makes those features stop working. WIth serverside you have to implement those features yourself, they won't be done by the plugin.

Comment: @ChrisH., if I turn off serverside processing then the table fails to render since the data is provided via an api. I will just keep digging for more details on the datatables website to see if I can come up with a better solution to my problem.

Comment: @beardedeagle Clientside processing and ajax-sourced data work together, I don't know where you got the idea that they don't. Read the documentation on serverside processing on the datatables webpage, as well as the documentation for ajax-sourced data.

Comment: See my edit.  Basically, have a look at the server side processing api.

Comment: Found https://gist.github.com/arkanus/3961705 which I am going to try to rip out what I need to be able to make mine work.